# Need redirection to particular page after login

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, http-referer

i have a secure login form and at the moment, i have set it to just redirect to a home page link, but i want to add some validation so that IF a user comes from a perticular page then they should be redirected to that page after logging in, but not sure how to do it, my current way is not working, here is what i have tried so far:

```
print $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
$previousPage = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if ($errors == "") {

    if (do_login($form_email_address,$form_password)) {
        // success!
            if ($previousPage == "http://hiddensite/path/video/"){
                redirect($previousPage);
            }else{
                redirect("/index.php?page=home&loggedin=1");
            }               
    } else {
        $errors = "Could not login. Please check your e-mail address and/or password and try again.";
    }
```

and if your wondering what redirect() is, its just my function:

```
function redirect($url) {

    // this function redirects from one page to another
    ob_clean();

    header("Location: $url");
    exit();

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you check for the referrer without the last slash?

Comment: 'not working' in what way? Is it redirecting you to the wrong page? Is it not redirecting at all?

Comment: it redirects me back to the homepage

Comment: How are you calling your `do_login()` function?

Comment: That should probably be `header("Location:" .$url);`

Comment: @Fred -ii- the redirect function is not the problem

Comment: For your `if (do_login($form_email_address,$form_password))` `do_login` is a function. And see my above comment also. @user3332590

Comment: What about removing the 'exit();' function in redirect function.

Comment: why would i do that..

Comment: It's ok, scratch that. I noticed you're using a session variable. Is `session_start();` loaded and in all your files? @user3332590

Comment: Because you are putting the function inside if else condition, you can put the exit in the if condition

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know if a user comes from another page on your own site? If so, you could add a session var to that previous page and test it on your login page.

On your previous page:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = "bar";
```

And on your login page -

```
if(isset($_SESSION['foo'])) {...}
```

Not a great way to keep track of referrers, but if you only want to check one page as per your question, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

We seem to be missing some information in answering your question. The code you have provided seems fine but in order for us to pinpoint the issue we would have to see the do_login function as you previously posted in the comments (which is now retracted). Since you are always redirected to the home page that would mean that the do_login function always returns false or anything else but true.

Before you retracted the comment I did noticed you also used the sqlslashes() function a few times. Is this a function that you have created? Be sure to include this in your question.